# Android Studio não encontra JDK durante instalação.Como resolver?

Tags: android-studio

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando instalar o Android Studio no meu Windows 7, porém ele nunca encontra a pasta com o jdk instalado.
Mesmo que eu aponte manualmente, ele não localiza. Já inseri as variáveis de ambiente conforme eu vi na web e nada acontece.

Eis as variáveis e seus valores:

> JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
>
> JDk_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
>
> STUDIO_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

Meu Windows é 32bits.

O que me está a faltar?

Comment: @toni-cesar-a-amaral coloquei um resposta aqui neste post, desça a página para ver a resposta...

Answer (score 4):

Lembre-se que a variavel de ambiente `JAVA_HOME` deve ser adicionada em **variaveis do sistema** e não em **Variaveis de usuário**.

Supondo que você fez a adição desta forma, adicione mais uma variável de sistema como segue abaixo:

> **Nome: CLASSPATH**
>
> **Valor: .;%JAVA_HOME%**

**- TOME CUIDADO NESTE PROCEDIMENTO SEGUINTE**

Depois, edite variavel **Path**, adicionando no final `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\`, que é a sua variavel criada anteriormente. Reinicie o pc e verifique se o jdk é reconhecido pelo sistema, abrindo uma tela de prompt de comando e executando o comando `javac`. Caso seja reconhecido, vai aparecer varias opções de ajuda deste comando.

Após isso, tente instalar o Android Studio, que provavelmente o JDK será reconhecido normalmente.

Obs.: Caso ainda sim não seja reconhecido, você pode tentar as dicas [**deste link**](https://software.intel.com/pt-br/forums/android-na-arquitetura-intel/topic/413812) ou [**deste aqui**](http://blog.dmatoso.com/2011/05/android-sdk-jdk-nao-encontrado/).

Comment: Também não deu certo, mas arrumei outra solução. Como eu estava tentando instalar pelo instalador (.exe) sem sucesso, decidir baixar o zip e rodá-lo. Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela força!