# Erro compilar Android Delphi-10 no Windows 10

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10

Estou com um problema para compilar para android no delphi-10, segue o erro

> [Exec Error] The command "PATH C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio.0\Bpl;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE7\IDE_spoof;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin; & "C:\Users\jeffe\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio.0\PlatformSDKs\android-sdk-windows\build-tools.0.1\dx.bat" --dex --output="C:\Users\jeffe\OneDrive\Programação\Mobile\ads100\Android\Debug\classes.dex" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-services.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-licensing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-play-billing.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\google-analytics-v2.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\fmx.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\cloud-messaging.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\apk-expansion.dex.jar" "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio.0\lib\Android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar" " exited with code 3.

Comment: Verifique se você possui as devidas permissões para essas pastas, compilar no delphi consiste em Gerar um Executável/APK e para isto você precisa de permissão!

Comment: Talvez não seja o problema, mas achei estranho uma coisa, teu Delphi é 32bit né? Você deveria instalar o java 32bit também, ou estou enganado?

Comment: Pelo oque eu vi em comentários pela net, o problema esta no caminho do path do java em variáveis de ambiente, mas tentei adicionar não funcionou, e apps de samples funcionam normalmente isto que é mais estranho

Comment: Mude a variável PATH assim: tecle `Windows + R` > digite `control` e tecle enter > `Sistema` > `Configurações avançadas de sistema` > em `Propriedades do Sistema` vá p/ aba `Avançado` > `Variáveis de Ambiente...` > em - `Variáveis do Sistema`- > edite a variável `PATH` > coloque o valor: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio.0\Bpl;C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\InterBase\redist\InterBaseXE7\IDE_spoof;` ou acesse: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96317/android-studio-n%C3%A3o-encontra-jdk-durante-instala%C3%A7%C3%A3o-como-resolver/127470

Comment: No meu caso foi só desinstalar o java 9 e voltou ao normal

Answer (score 0):

Meu caso estava parecido, com a mesma mensagem atualizei para o `java versão 8`

Em `tools>>options>>sdk manager` entre no `java` e configure para a nova pasta `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\keytool.exe` e a outra para a mesma pasta, funcionou para mim.

Answer (score 0):

Comigo resolvi este problema no Delphi Berlin da seguinte forma: 
Na tela PROJECT MANAGER (à direita) vá em Android SDK --->> CONFIGURATION e verifique se a opção Application Store esta DESATIVADA deixando a outra opção existente ativada, depois logo abaixo em LIBRARIES clique com o botão direito em cada opção listada e desative.

Answer (score 0):

Tente Atualizar o java como a resposta do Sr. Luiz caso não funcione tente atualizar também o **SDk** e **NDK** o Caminho é: `Tools > Options > Environment Options > SDK Manager.` nas Abas **SDk** e **NDK** e **Java** verifique se tem algum item marcado de vermelho ou com uma plaquinha com uma exclamação. Depois de Atualiza voltar ao normal.