# Erro ao utilizar javac no prompt de comando

Tags: java

Fiz os procedimentos nas variáveis de ambiente porem não funciona o comando javac.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @bigown, na verdade ela é até duplicata dessa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96317/28595

Comment: Desta forma não tem muito como ajudar, mas está claro que não fez tudo o que precisava. Tem que informar como está tudo no seu ambie nte pra ver onde está o erro.

Comment: @Articuno pode ser mesmo

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g43w5d - Classpath

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g43wdl - Java Home

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g43wnm - PAth

Comment: @bigown ta ai um print

Comment: `"C: \ program files \ java \ jdk1.xx.xx_xx \ bin \ javac.exe"  `A partir do prompt de comando. Você também pode dizer qual executável (se houver) está sendo usado com o comando:--

`for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo %~$PATH:i`  
Este é um truque limpo semelhante ao que e / ou de onde comandos em alguns sistemas operacionais do tipo UNIX.

Comment: Se o problema não e classpath, então não tem como saber só com essa imagem. Tente fazer o procedimento do zero. Reinstale o JDK, depois adicionr-o nas variaveis de ambiente do windows, conforme explica o link, reinicie o pc e tente rodar novamente.

Comment: Fica bem mais fácil se você postar o texto na pergunta ao invés dessas imagens. Além disso, ao invés de ficar postando comentários com links, seria mais fácil se você editasse a pergunta. Fica a dica.